# Finding best path trought strongly connected component

Tags: cycle, directed-graph

I have a directed graph which is strongly connected and every node have some price(plus or negative). I would like to find best (highest score) path from node A to node B. My solution is some kind of brutal force so it takes ages to find that path. Is any algorithm for this or any idea how can I do it?

Comment: Can the path contain cycles?

Comment: If you want something like Dijkstra's, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Yes it contain cycle. This graph is strongly connected (you can get from node any to another node)

Comment: @Amsik- Sorry, to clarify - can *the path that you find* from node A to node B contain cycles, or does it have to be a simple path?

Comment: @EmmadKareem- Dijkstra's algorithm can't handle negative edge weights.

Comment: Yes path from node A to node B can contain cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)?

It's a fairly popular pathfinding algorithm. 
The algorithm itself is not to difficult to implement, but there are plenty of implementations available online.

Dijkstra's algorithm is a special case for the A* (in which the heuristic function h(x) = 0).

There are other algorithms who can outperform it, but they usually require graph pre-processing. If the problem is not to complex and you're looking for a quick solution, give it a try.

**EDIT:**

For graphs containing negative edges, there's the [Bellman–Ford](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~zjb/courses/800/lec15-1.pdf) algorithm. Detecting the negative cycles comes at the cost of performance, though (worse than the A*). But it still may be better than what you're currently using.

**EDIT 2:**

User @templatetypedef is right when he says the Bellman-Ford algorithm may not work in here.

The B-F works with graphs where there are edges with negative weight. However, the algorithm stops upon finding a negative cycle. I believe that is a useful behavior. Optimizing the shortest path in a graph that contains a cycle of negative weights will be like going down a Penrose staircase.

What should happen if there's the possibility of reaching a path with "minus infinity cost" depends on the problem.

Comment: A* doesn't handle negative costs correctly, and I don't believe this will work here.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that. Thanks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I don't believe Bellman-Ford will work here. The graph may have negative cycles in it, which will cause Bellman-Ford not to work correctly.